# php curl empty reply from server

Tags: php, curl, reply

I have a problem with php curl. 
I am using this script

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // header will be at output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($content === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
$output = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
if (curl_error($ch))
$output .= "\n". curl_error($ch);
print $output;
}
else {
print $content;
}
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

I am trying to connect to this website: kaztorka.org but gives me "empty reply from server" error. However it works fine with console CURL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked whether curl extension is enabled or not in php?

If not, please edit your `php.ini` and **uncomment** `;extension=php_curl.dll` i.e. remove the trailing semicolon.

Comment: yes. it is enabled. it works with other websites. it only doesnt work with that specific site(kaztorka.org). but i can send request using console curl and server replies.

Comment: figured out. the problem was with host server itself